# JS filter what is item[key]?

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I have the following which works but has me confused. Could someone explain what item[key] refers to?

```js
const items=[{name:"Joe",occupied:"no",mobile:"yes",treatment:"no",date:"29-03-2020",age:"15",stuff:["A","B","C"],type:["1","2"]},{name:"Jack",occupied:"yes",mobile:"no",treatment:"no",date:"02-03-2020",age:"20",stuff:["A","B","C","D","E"],type:["8","6"],misc:["otherStuff","someStuff"]},{name:"Jane",occupied:"no",mobile:"yes",treatment:"yes",date:"15-02-2020",age:"28",stuff:["C","D","E"],type:["4","7"],something:["xxx","ccc"]}];

const keysWithArrays = new Set(
  items.flatMap(
     item => Object.keys(item).filter(key => Array.isArray(item[key]))   
  )
);

console.log([...keysWithArrays]);
```

Comment: item[key] is each element in the `item` object

Answer (score 1):

For an object, `item`, eg

```
{
  name:"Joe",
  occupied:"no",
}
```

Iterating over the keys of it with `Object.keys` gives you `['name', 'occupied']`. Accessing `item[key]` on the object will give you the value at that key, eg `'Joe'` or `'no'`.

Here's another way of doing the same thing, but with `Object.entries`, which gives an array of entries (key-value pairs, as an array: `[[key, value], [key, value], [key, value]]` ) instead of an array of keys (`[key, key, key]`):

```js
const items=[{name:"Joe",occupied:"no",mobile:"yes",treatment:"no",date:"29-03-2020",age:"15",stuff:["A","B","C"],type:["1","2"]},{name:"Jack",occupied:"yes",mobile:"no",treatment:"no",date:"02-03-2020",age:"20",stuff:["A","B","C","D","E"],type:["8","6"],misc:["otherStuff","someStuff"]},{name:"Jane",occupied:"no",mobile:"yes",treatment:"yes",date:"15-02-2020",age:"28",stuff:["C","D","E"],type:["4","7"],something:["xxx","ccc"]}];

const keysWithArrays = new Set(
  items.flatMap(
     item => Object.entries(item)
                   .filter(([key, value]) => Array.isArray(value))
                   .map(([key]) => key)
  )
);

console.log([...keysWithArrays]);
```

(but this requires an extra `.map` at the end)